# how to send api data in nodejs For Example given as the description box

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

**Let's say I have an array of objects:**

It stores multiple values in a single variable. The object can contain like a Username, amount etc.
Actually, I store the same object of the data in the single objects like a define in the description.
So, help me every one can solve this problem.
please solve this problem.

````
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "Username": "Rajesh",
        "Amount": "3000",
        "Account_name": "Rahul",
        "Google_pay": "",
        "Phone_pay": "9794368090",
        "Paytm": "",
        "Account_holder_name": "",
        "Ifsc": "",
        "Date": "2021-12-16T13:47:19.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "Username": "john$123",
        "Amount": "3000",
        "Account_name": "Rahul",
        "Google_pay": "",
        "Phone_pay": "9794368090",
        "Paytm": "",
        "Account_holder_name": "",
        "Ifsc": "",
        "Date": "2021-12-16T13:47:19.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "Username": "alex",
        "Amount": "2000",
        "Account_name": "Rahul",
        "Google_pay": "",
        "Phone_pay": "",
        "Paytm": "9794368090",
        "Account_holder_name": "",
        "Ifsc": "",
        "Date": "2021-12-16T13:47:19.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "Username": "rajesh",
        "Amount": "1000",
        "Account_name": "Rahul",
        "Google_pay": "",
        "Phone_pay": "9794368090",
        "Paytm": "",
        "Account_holder_name": "",
        "Ifsc": "",
        "Date": "2021-12-16T13:47:19.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "Username": "rahul1",
        "Amount": "1000",
        "Account_name": "Rahul",
        "Google_pay": "",
        "Phone_pay": "9794368090",
        "Paytm": "",
        "Account_holder_name": "",
        "Ifsc": "",
        "Date": "2021-12-16T13:47:19.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "Username": "john$123",
        "Amount": "2000",
        "Account_name": "xyz",
        "Google_pay": "9794368090",
        "Phone_pay": "",
        "Paytm": "",
        "Account_holder_name": "",
        "Ifsc": "",
        "Date": "2021-12-16T13:51:20.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "Username": "rajesh",
        "Amount": "1200",
        "Account_name": "asfsddfs",
        "Google_pay": "",
        "Phone_pay": "",
        "Paytm": "8778979",
        "Account_holder_name": "",
        "Ifsc": "",
        "Date": "2021-12-17T08:42:17.000Z"
    }
]```

However, I can't seem to get an array that looks like this

```{
    "john$123": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "Username": "john$123",
            "Amount": "3000",
            "Account_name": "Rahul",
            "Google_pay": "",
            "Phone_pay": "9794368090",
            "Paytm": "",
            "Account_holder_name": "",
            "Ifsc": "",
            "Date": "2021-12-16T13:47:19.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "Username": "john$123",
            "Amount": "2000",
            "Account_name": "xyz",
            "Google_pay": "9794368090",
            "Phone_pay": "",
            "Paytm": "",
            "Account_holder_name": "",
            "Ifsc": "",
            "Date": "2021-12-16T13:51:20.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "alex": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "Username": "alex",
            "Amount": "2000",
            "Account_name": "Rahul",
            "Google_pay": "",
            "Phone_pay": "",
            "Paytm": "9794368090",
            "Account_holder_name": "",
            "Ifsc": "",
            "Date": "2021-12-16T13:47:19.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "rajesh": [
        {
           "id": 2,
            "Username": "Rajesh",
            "Amount": "3000",
            "Account_name": "Rahul",
            "Google_pay": "",
            "Phone_pay": "9794368090",
            "Paytm": "",
            "Account_holder_name": "",
            "Ifsc": "",
            "Date": "2021-12-16T13:47:19.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "Username": "rajesh",
            "Amount": "1000",
            "Account_name": "Rahul",
            "Google_pay": "",
            "Phone_pay": "9794368090",
            "Paytm": "",
            "Account_holder_name": "",
            "Ifsc": "",
            "Date": "2021-12-16T13:47:19.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "Username": "rajesh",
            "Amount": "1200",
            "Account_name": "asfsddfs",
            "Google_pay": "",
            "Phone_pay": "",
            "Paytm": "8778979",
            "Account_holder_name": "",
            "Ifsc": "",
            "Date": "2021-12-17T08:42:17.000Z"
        }
    ],
    "rahul1": [
        {
            "id": 10,
            "Username": "rahul1",
            "Amount": "1000",
            "Account_name": "Rahul",
            "Google_pay": "",
            "Phone_pay": "9794368090",
            "Paytm": "",
            "Account_holder_name": "",
            "Ifsc": "",
            "Date": "2021-12-16T13:47:19.000Z"
        }
    ]
}``
I have been able to make some sort of headway, but can not quite get the exact result I need. Any guidance is greatly appreciated, thanks!
21
````

Comment: It will be good if you share some examples and try something. and share in js fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you correctly but you just want to get the information for a user with a specific username correct?

If so, then you can use .filter() on your first object, like I have shown below

```js
let array = [] //your original array
let username = "rajesh" //the username whose info you want to get
let userData = array.filter(results => results.Username.toLowerCase() === username.toLowerCase())
console.log(userData) //this will contain all the elements that had their username the same as the username in the username variable (case insensitive)

//do stuff with the new filtered user data
```

Now if you want the data as json with the key being the username, you can just do this

```js
let returnData = {}
returnData[username] = userData
return returnData
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Sir